# How To Check If Username Is Already Exists In a MySQL Table show hidden password field

Tags: php, ajax

this is my html form .

```
<form id="login" action="">

            <input name="username" id="username" value="" maxlength="100" type="text" />
          <div>username:</div>

          <div id="lay_pw" style="display:none">
            <input name="password" id="password" value="" type="password" />
          <div>password:</div>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" name="go" value="login" class="main_btn1" />

        </form>
```

i want to check if username already exists in mysql database show hidden password field if username not exists transmission user For example index.php . i want to use ajax check

Comment: `if username not exists transmission user` What?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: I think that your problem is now solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)**Create a new folder in your Root directory**. Put inside it the 3 following files:

2)Create a HTML file name it "**index.php**" then copy/paste this code inside it and save it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr_FR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="check_username.js"></script>
    <title>Username check</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="login" action="" method="post">
       <div>username:</div>
        <input name="username" id="username" value="" maxlength="100" type="text" onkeyup="checkUsername();" />
       <div id="lay_pw" style="display:none">
        <div>password:</div>
        <input name="password" id="password" value="" type="password" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="go" value="login" class="main_btn1" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

3)Create a javascript file and name it "**check_username.js**", then copy/paste this code inside it and save it.

```
$.customPOST = function(data,callback){
    $.post('check_username.php',data,callback,'json');
}
//when typing, the script checks if the username exists
function checkUsername() {
  $.customPOST({username: $('#username').val()},function(r){
    //username exists
    if(r.exists == 'yes'){
     $( "#lay_pw" ).toggle(400,function(){});
    }
    else{
     $( "#lay_pw" ).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
}
```

4)Create a PHP file, name it "**check_username.php**", copy/paste this code inside it and save it.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('database');
$response = 'no';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != ''){
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'", $link);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $response = 'yes';
 }
}
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $response));
?>
```

5)Use this sample database (i used it for testing this stuff)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `password`) VALUES
('test1', '5a105e8b9d40e1329780d62ea2265d8a'),
('test2', 'ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b'),
('alpha', '2c1743a391305fbf367df8e4f069f9f9'),
('beta', '987bcab01b929eb2c07877b224215c92');
```

Comment: thank you , but not worked i have problem with php

Comment: what kind of problem ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\login\index.php on line 45 {"exists":null}

Comment: paste your php code to debug it

Comment: I do not want to click on the image to Check i want after click login button if user exists Hide password field is displayed

Comment: Is the form used for signing up ? I mean that your form is just used to login ?
What is your goal in hiding password, if the user type it first ?

Comment: i want to use this form for login guest and Registered Users

Comment: Sorry but there is no sense to login guests. But in order to achieve your request, just remove the image from the HTML and change the ID of the clicked object: for example if your login button has an ID : #login_button, change "#btnCheck" in "#login_button". And in the response function change the statement :  if(r.exists == 'yes')

Comment: not worked checked beta user got the password field is not displayed

Comment: Demo files, try it yourself
[link]http://sharesend.com/u22062pk

Comment: This script does not work on the local host I got this working on a site http://ilx.ir Is awesome 
Very 
  Grateful

Comment: If your problem is solved, then change the status of this post to SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

this is my check.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('inc/dbConnect.inc.php');
$message=array();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
}else{
    $message[]='Please enter username';
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
}else{
    $message[]='Please enter password';
}

$countError=count($message);

if($countError > 0){
     for($i=0;$i<$countError;$i++){
              echo ucwords($message[$i]).'<br/><br/>';
     }
}else{
    $query="select * from user where username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $res=mysql_query($query);
    $checkUser=mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($checkUser > 0){
         $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
         $_SESSION['username']=$username;
         echo 'correct';
    }else{
         echo ucwords('please enter correct user details');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is your login script, but I posted a check script which is different from yours. You want to hide password input when the user+password is matching. I my opinion that's makes no sense, but it's your idea.

Comment: Do you know the script of a et-chat?

Comment: can you send me a sample?

Comment: Look at the solution ;)

Comment: Just copy/paste in new files, for example the javascript will be within a file named "check_username.js" and the PHP file "check_username.php"

Comment: i have problem with this line $.customPOST = function(data,callback){
    $.post('http://url.to/check.php',data,callback,'json');

Comment: Can you go online on yahoo? this is my yahoo id "ebi_64"